# Possible to find nearby places using Google places API for Android (as opposed to Web Service API)?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

There seem to be multiple questions regarding finding nearby places within a radius of the current (or a specified) location through Google Places API. Most answers seem to be using the Web Service API, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30162174/2671179). However, I haven't found an answer accomplishing this through the Google Places API for Android. Is this possible?

I saw that, at least 2 years ago, the API for iOS did not have support for this (if I understand [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32061766/2671179) correctly). Is this still true? And is the situation the same for Android?

Looking at the [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start), it seems to suggest this, as I don't see it in the list of guides.

Comment: I am looking for the same, and it seems it is not possible at the moment, the Android Place API does not have all the features the Web Place API has.